# light box on page load instead of onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**Question**

I want to trigger light box on page load . instead of on click event . any suggestion please.

I also read documentation of light box but no success :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the lightbox initiation on load, this would define click events on the image links, then trigger one of the click events, like it was clicked right on load.

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
    $('#gallery a').eq(0).click();
});
```

**EDIT:** `first()` is [only available since jQuery 1.4](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [jQuery lightBox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) is bundled with version 1.2.3, use `eq(0)` instead.

Comment: i do this but it do nothing :-(